# undefined method `model_name' for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for

I want to set up my models, such that my Posts has_many Comments and Comments has_many Replies. Comments are working fine. But my application starts breaking saying

```
undefined method `model_name' for "/posts/adas/comments/11/replies":String
```

when I try to setup the replies for comments. I cannot figure out what's triggering this error. I can add replies from my Rails console, and see them in the view, but adding the form_for tag breaks the code. Can anybody please point out what is the mistake and how I should be routing it?

Posts#show.html.erb

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
    <b><%= comment.username %></b>
    <%= comment.name %>
    <% if current_user.email == comment.username || current_user.admin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment], 
        :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
    <p style = "text-indent: 3em">
        <% comment.replies.each do |reply| %>
            <i><%= reply.author %></i>
            <%= reply.content %>
        <% end %>
<%= form_for [@reply, post_comment_replies_path(@post, comment)] do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :reply %>
        <%= f.text_field :content %>
        <%= f.submit("Reply") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</p>
</p>
<h3>Add a comment:</h3>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :comment %><br />
<%= f.text_area :name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

replies_controller.rb

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @reply = @comment.replies.create(reply_params)
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
    private
      def reply_params
        params.require(:reply).permit(:content)
      end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do 
      resources :replies
    end
    member do
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you're not passing the parameters in the proper way to get the result that you want. At the moment you're passing in a url string where rails is expecting a resource object, hence the undefined method exception.

> form_for(record, options = {}, &block)

The method takes a record and a hash of options that are optional.

The suspect line is

```
<%= form_for [@reply, post_comment_replies_path(@post, comment)] do |f| %>
```

The square brackets should only be used to define a resource and its associated resources which are then used to generate a url path. You should also explicitly state your url in the options hash unless it can be inferred from the resources you pass into form_for.

So it should look something like this, keeping with the way you are doing things.

```
<%= form_for @reply, url: post_comment_replies_path(@post, comment) do |f| %>
```

That's the case if you want to specify a url in form_for. However, why don't you just allow rails to generate the url for you?

```
<%= form_for [@post, comment, @reply] do |f| %>
```

This way rails should handle the routes.

Comment: `<%= form_for @reply, url: post_comment_replies_path(@post, comment) do |f| %>`

gives the same error.

And `<%= form_for [@post, comment, @reply] do |f| %>` says first argument cannot be empty.